# Add values of a List object in Single line C#

Tags: c#, linq

Am having a list object. i need to add the values in the object in a single line of code without using foreach or for loop. Is it possible using the linq query??

For eg: am having a list object userCount of length 2. I need to find the TotalManagerCount by adding the ManagerCount values in the list.

```
public class UserCount
{
public int ManagerCount {get; set;}
public int EngineerCount {get; set;}
}

List<UserCount> userCount = new List<UserCount>();

int TotalManagerCount = ??
int TotalEngineerCount = ??
```

Thanks in advance

Dinesh.

Comment: Do you try userCount.Sum(s=>s.ManagerCount) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use LINQ [Sum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549046(v=vs.110).aspx) function:

```
int TotalManagerCount = userCount.Sum(x=>x.ManagerCount);
int TotalEngineerCount = userCount.Sum(x=>x.EngineerCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`Sum`](https://www.google.lk/search?q=linq%20sum&rlz=1C1CHBD_enLK743LK743&oq=linq%20sum&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2.1431j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)** function of Linq

```
int TotalManagerCount = userCount.Sum(item => item.ManagerCount);
int TotalEngineerCount = userCount.Sum(item => item.EngineerCount);
```